# Real Time Javascript Event Tracking (Javascript Stats)

Tags: javascript, events, google-analytics, tracking

There are lots of real time web stats services on the web (w3counter-histats-gostats).They just count once when page is requested , But what I want to do is track javascript functions/events, because my website is fully-ajax.So I want something like google analytic's event tracker (http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApiEventTracking.html) , but real time , and very simple .It can be hosted or just a php script.Thank you .

### example events

- user created something
- user deleted something
- ajax error happend
- browser eror happend
- user logged in

### I found my answer take a look

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's **not so hard** to implement **your own**. You just send **request to the server** when an event happens like: `tracker.gif?action=create&what=sth`, `tracker.gif?action=error&what=k_is_undefined`, etc.

Then you **parse the server logs**  for the stats. (or you send your request right into the database by `tracker.php?action=create&what=sth`)

Since you control the site it's now easy to make these requests when a user logs in, or an ajax request fails.

For error handling you can use `window.onerror`:

```
// send a request about an event to the server
function fireEvent(action, message, options) {
  var loggerUrl = "/tracker.gif", parameters;
  options = options || {};
  options.url = options.url || window.location.href;
  options.user_agent = navigator.userAgent;
  options.message = message;
  for (var i in options) {
    if (options.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      parameters += "&" + i + "=" + encodeURIComponent(options[i]);
    }
  }    
  new Image().src = loggerUrl + parameters;
}

// log script errors
window.onerror = function(errorMessage, url, line) {   
  fireEvent("error", errorMessage, {
    url: url, 
    line: line
  });
  return true;
};

// example event on the page
fireEvent("ajaxError", "XY page failed to load");
```

(note: `window.onerror` is not available in safari)

---

> ### UPDATE

And here is a proof of concept for a PHP parser:

```
$i = 1;
$d = file_get_contents("log.txt");
$requests = explode("\n", $d);
foreach ($requests as $req) {
  $pos = strpos($req, "tracker.gif");
  if ($pos === false) continue;
  $start_pos = strpos($req, "?", $pos);
  $end_pos = strpos($req, " ", $start_pos); // can also be " HTTP"
  $length = $end_pos - $start_pos;
  $req = substr($req, $start_pos+1, $length);
  $exprs = explode("&", $req);
  echo $i . ".<br>"; // request number
  $i += 1;
  foreach ($exprs as $expr) {
    list($name, $value) = explode("=", $expr);
    echo $name . " =>" . $value . "<br>"; // key => value
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting alternative solution which I have not seen before (tracker.gif).

Comment: Google Analytics does the same thing actually. Interesting means you're gonna try it out?

Comment: Yes. I am testing it right now , but my current problem is parsing log file , Dou you have any idea to parse it easily .

Comment: x.x.x.32 - - [08/Jul/2010:16:58:24 -0700] "GET /example.com/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 356 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_4; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.99 Safari/533.4" ------- this is one line

Comment: I like this , perfect .Thank you .

Answer (score 5):

If you're using jQuery, you can run code during the [`$.ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) event

Comment: This is not related to my question. I asked what is the best way to record all these events and errors to database and report time live.

Comment: how is it not related? i don't know what stat tracking program you're using. i simply gave you a method to run code to track when something happens. completely relevant if you ask me.

Comment: I did not asked How to detect AjaxSucces . I asked how to track all my javascript event , record and report them .

Comment: It is related, a do-it-yourself solution.

Comment: @oguz Of course you didn't ask how to detect ajax success. that would be a silly, self-answering question. you asked "my page is ajax. i need a way to track hits. How do i do this?" i responded with, "run your hit tracking code during the ajaxsuccess event". i'm not going to tell you step by step how to track your own analytics! how would i know anything about your database, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Analytics and _trackPageview() as outlined [here!](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55521)

Edit: If that doesn't give you the solution that you are looking for, I think you are looking for a service that doesn't yet exist, in which case, take Jason's `$.ajaxSuccess()` suggestion and make your own.

Comment: I am asking that If there is a php script like that , or if there is a free service likte that.

Answer (score 0):

**This is what I am looking for , Unfortunately, This is not free , But I hope I will find one .**

http://mixpanel.com

Comment: checkout kissmetrics.com, it's in a private beta but a really cool product

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of options if you google for "real time analytics". But most of them are paid.

I'd recommend mixpanel and chartbeat.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking, I've found great pleasure in using [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) as an open source alternative.

For tracking events there's the good JavaScript client, with [some documentation](http://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/tracking-javascript).

For event tracking I'm using this plain function where needed:

```
_paq.push( [ 'category', 'action', 'name', 'value' ] );
```

Then you can export all data from the web views of Piwik or directly query the DB for retrieving information, if you are hosting the Piwik on your server.